# Atualizar dados aplicativo Android

Tags: android

Ainda não tenho o projeto em execução, mas estou desenvolvendo um app que mostre o cardápio de um restaurante universitario. A parte que estou em duvidas é a atualização do cardapio semanalmente.

Ja usei FTP para atualizar um arquivo txt no Android, e pensei em montar um cardapio em um arquivo txt, salvar em um servidor FTP e o app se comunicar com esse servidor e realizar o download do arquivo TXT.

O app tem 5 botões ratio (um para cada semana). No caso pensei em 5 arquivos contendo o cardapio de cada dia, baixo esses arquivos e mostro em um textrView por dia da semana.

Funcionaria? E teria algum jeito mais simples?

Comment: Olá Gustavo Rotondo, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Percebi que teve várias perguntas fechadas recentemente. Sugiro que para aumentar suas chances de conseguir uma boa resposta leia o guia [ask] e faça um [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funcionaria sim, esse aí parece o mais simples e não o mais correto.

O mais correto seria usar um servidor WEB pode ser WCF C# ASP.NET ou algum outro.

E esse servidor WCF pegaria de um banco de dados.

http://www.mobiltec.com.br/blog/index.php/tutorial-de-android-requisicao-de-servicos-de-um-servidor-wcf-parte-1/

Esse modo que falei é um pouco mais "caro e demorado" de se fazer, porém é o mais correto.

De qualquer modo, o que você falou em fazer funcionaria sim.